# Unable to grow Windows 2019 C: system partition

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019, diskmanagement

I have a software vendor supplied 2019 Server virtual, with a very simple one partition setup. Unlike many of similar questions I've come across while searching, this one does not have recovery partition at the end. I grew the disk in VMWare by 100GiB, but Disk Management refuses to grow the C: -partition into the newly added space.

I have not previously encountered a situation where free adjacent space was not usable for growing existing partitions. Is there anything else that would be preventing me from extending it?

[image: Disk Manager]

Comment: Im assuming the extend the volume option is greyed out? Have you restarted the machine yet? Seems you may need to reboot or if page file is enable, maybe disable it and extend the volume, https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004071

Comment: Extend is not grayed out, it just doesn't allow entering larger partition size than it already is. The virtual has been shut down once. The pagefile might be the culprit here, but I'm wondering why it wasn't an issue with any of our development Win10 virtuals that I've enlarged earlier.

Comment: It was the page file, would you add this as an answer, @Kelv.Gonzales ?

Answer (score 2):

As @Kelv.Gonzales suggested, page file appeared to cause this. I disabled it, rebooted and after that I was able to extend the partition normally.

Comment: It's common to ask people who provided the solution in a comment to post it as an answer, so they can earn the credit they are due.

Comment: My bad. Will take care of it.